# Need help in understanding the answer of the Big-O complexity for this code

Tags: c, time-complexity

According to the answer key, the answer is O(N). I didn't have enough time to see it carefully. I thought it was i++ and not i/=2 in the first loop so I wrote O(N^2). But now I am not sure what is the correct. I think it should be O(log n * log n).

Code:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = N; i > 0; i /=2)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        count++;
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I uploaded the wrong picture earlier. It is updated now, @Yunnosch

Comment: The outer loop is o(logn), the inner though is o(n) , hence we have o(nlogn)  if i am not mistaken

Comment: @vpa1977, complexity logic isn't that simple. It's `O(N)` for the reasons of `r3mainder`'s answer.

Comment: Hence i am mistaken -)

Comment: It depends on what `N` is. If it's a constant you can toss "big O" out the window, because the loops will get optimized away and learning which "big O" they would have had if they weren't isn't very useful knowledge. It's better to understand how programs, compilers and computers actually work.

Comment: See this https://godbolt.org/z/f1T9jT8bG. The time complexity is the number of CPU ticks it takes to load a fixed integer into a register...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- At the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop is performed N times
- At the second iteration, the inner loop is performed N/2 times
- At each subsequent iteration, the inner loop is performed half as many times as in the previous iteration

The total number of iterations is equal to N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1, which is approximately equal to 2N.

Therefore, the total number of iterations is O(N)

Comment: At the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop is performed N times. At the second iteration, the inner loop is performed N/2 times. So, the code runs for more than N times why is the time complexity O(N). Shouldn't it be O(N*log N) ? @Elliott

Comment: It's a geometric sequence with q = 1/2

Comment: @UnknownHuman, you'll understand why `r3mainder` is right if you learn about how to sum a geometric sequence.

Comment: Oh ok. I understood it now. Its time complexity is O(n+log n) which is written as O(n). Thanks. This was not an easy question, at least for beginners..

Comment: @UnknownHuman, sorry, but that's still not it. It's actually roughly `O(2N)`, but we drop the constant factors, so it becomes `O(N)`

Comment: The answer would be nlogn if the inner loop had full N iterations every time. But since we are doing division by 2, the answer changes - we arrive to at most 2N iterations as per answer and o(n) complexity